# Complex conjugation of positive roots

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

I have a simple question about root systems. Suppose that $G$ is a connected reductive group over the reals $\mathbb{R}$, and $T\subset G$ is a maximal torus (by this I mean that $T_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a maximal torus in $G_{\mathbb{C}}$). Let $R$ be the root system of $(G_{\mathbb{C}},T_{\mathbb{C}})$, and choose a set of positive roots $R^+$. Complex conjugation $\iota$ acts by Galois action on the characters of $T_{\mathbb{C}}$, and if $\chi$ is a root, then $\iota(\chi)$ is also a root.

I wonder if it's always true that if $\chi\in R^+$ then $\iota(\chi)$ is a negative root.

Comment: What if $G$ is split and $T$ is a split torus?

Comment: Is your torus compact?  Is that what is going on?

Comment: Not compact in general. But your counterexample with split $G$ and $T$ shows that the answer is no in general. Maybe if $G$ is not split?..

Comment: @dedekind: The question isn't formulated very clearly yet.   It seems you are looking at a real form of a complex semisimple Lie group (or algebraic group) $G$ ("reductive" isn't directly relevant here).   But when you fix a maximal torus of $G$ and consider the resulting root system, how are using the chosen real form to make a choice of positive roots?  The literature on Lie groups (by Vogan and many others) requires a lot of relative notation over $\mathbb{R}$ to deal with roots in this situation.

Comment: Jim, indeed, I realized it doesn't make much sense. The choice of positive roots is arbitrary and in principle has nothing to do with the real structure, which would mean that my question is ill-posed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@dedekind: not so ill-posed, it just depends on the Cartan and set of positive roots. You are given a complex group G, a real structure $\sigma$, a $\sigma$-fixed Cartan H. Then $\sigma$ permutes the roots, and there are 3 possibilities.

1. $\sigma\alpha=\alpha$ ($\alpha$ is "real")
2. $\sigma\alpha=-\alpha$ ($\alpha$ is "imaginary")
3. $\sigma\alpha\ne\pm\alpha$ ($\alpha$ is "complex")

Obviously real positive roots stay positive, and imaginary roots change sign, independent of the choice of positive roots. The issue is the complex roots, which can either switch sign or not, depending on the choice of positive roots. It turns out that, given a Cartan, you can always choose a set of positive roots such that $\alpha>0$ complex$\Rightarrow\sigma(\alpha)>0$ (alternatively $\alpha>0$ complex $ \Rightarrow\sigma\alpha<0$).

So the answer depends on both the Cartan and the set of positive roots.
If you want to make this hold for all roots, you need to know there are no compact (resp. real) roots, which is a slightly longer story.

See Vogan's "big green book" from 1981, starting on page 4.